# Cannot redirect to new url using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

I have a html web page and on the logo of the site, I wrote my logo URL as

`example.com` and I now want to redirect all requests made to `example.com` to go to `http://www.example.com`

This is my `.htaccess` so far:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/404.html 
 Redirect /index.html http://www.example.com

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`example.com` is not being redirected to `http://www.example.com`.

Comment: I think you need a `^` in the rewrite rule `^(.*)$` otherwise you don't know what you're matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.